# How to compare version of a specific NuGet package inside .csprog file

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, csproj, conditional-compilation

I am using conditional compilation and in the condition I need to compare the installed version of a specific Nuget package with the given version. Can this be done inside `.csprog` file?

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="MyPackages.AlphaPackage" Version="2.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="True"> <!-- Here I want to check if Version of MyPackages.AlphaPackage is 2.0.1 -->
    <DefineConstants>Version2Installled</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```